# How to test android library affect application's performance?

Tags: android, performance, performance-testing

I am building some android application. And of course it use many library included in gradle.

I want to do performance test, which library can  affect much my application performance for doing other logic , like encode and decode, or other stuff.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

There's an entire section in the Android User Guide called [Profile Your App](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/index.html). There's a number of tools you can use to measure the performance of your app, however an extensive performance testing will probably be time consuming. Normally you'd have to identify a problem in your app and pick appropriate profiling techniques to find out what causes it.

Comment: I'm looking for some tools that can use to  test my included library performance ,that cause the application slow,  forget about bad  display performance, or exhaust the battery like explain [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Egor's answer about profiling, you may also want to think about the [method count limit](http://www.methodscount.com/about) when considering library dependencies, in particular on older devices. While not directly related to runtime performance, having to use multidex in your builds will significantly increase your build times and the initial loading time of your app (on Android older than Lollipop).